# Designing the type system of a simple statically typed language (in Haskell)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, interpreter, type-systems

I've been toying with the idea of writing an interpreter for an imperative, statically typed language to get used to functional programming and Haskell, however I've never really had a clear grammar in mind, which often lead to unsatisfying code and the urge to rewrite everything so I came here for help. How should I go about designing a relatively simple but extensible type system?

I want to support basic primitives like numeric types, booleans, chars, etc. (don't want to dabble with arrays or record structures until I've got the basics in place) and their associated basic operations. My biggest issue is that I don't exactly know how the relation between types and operators should be implemented.

I don't know much about Haskell yet, but the simple solution of defining a bunch of repetitive sum types like

```
data ArithmeticOperator =
    Plus
    | Min
    | Mul 
    | Div

data LogicalOperator =
    And
    | Or
    | Not
```

doesn't seem to eloquent to me, since this type division would further propagate into the structures that build upon these types like expressions, and having to pattern match each operator when evaluating expressions seems really tedious and not easily extendable.

So then I thought about defining a flexible type for operators, like

```
data Operator a b =
    UnaryOperator (a -> b)
    | BinaryOperator (a -> a -> b)
```

where a stands for the parameters type and b is the return type. Problem with this is that I don't really know how to enforce the types to be only the ones that I intend to support. It looks more concise but I'm not sure if this is "right" either.

Finally, are there any resources that introduce this topic in a beginner friendly way? I wouldn't want to get too deep in the subject, but I'd love to read about.. well, common principles/considerations when it comes to designing a type system.

Comment: As pure functional-programs don't neatly represent a sequence of instructions (only their monads do, and even then it's not exactly a 1:1 representation to machine-code) I'm not certain it's possible to truly "interpret" a functional language like Haskell without doing whole-program analysis first - which essentially becomes compilation (you just end-up evaluating abstract machine-code instructions instead of raw machine instructions). But still, I wish you good luck and I want to see where this goes!

Comment: @Dai Of course it's possible to interpret purely functional languages. I don't understand why not "neatly represent[ing] a sequence of instructions" would make that harder. If anything, it would make compilation harder (but certainly not impossible).

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928608/typed-abstract-syntax-and-dsl-design-in-haskell/38601492#38601492) for a basic well-scoped and well-typed imperative setup. I think using different GADTs for unary & binary operations is a good idea.

Comment: @Tyrone_87 I think you'll have a much easier time if you keep your AST untyped (i.e. just `data Operator = ...` with no type parameters). In terms of sum types vs. functions, I'd say that the former are certainly more common than the latter, but either way will work and there's nothing wrong with experimenting. Note that the latter way won't allow you to derive `Show` or to otherwise meaningfully display your AST, so that's going to make debugging harder.

Comment: You also won't be able to pattern match on specific operators, so you'd need to store any information you need about the operator (such as its type and its name for error messages) along with the function.

Comment: Have you made a dynamically typed one yet? Much easier, and I would not wish someone to venture into implementing a type system who hasn't seen how this all fits together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the comments, don't try this as your first interpreter.  If you haven't already written an interpreter for the untyped lambda calculus or worked your way through a tutorial, like [Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours), do that first.

Anyway, here's a simple implementation of an interpreter for a statically typed expression language with boolean and number types, a few built-in operators (including one with ad-hoc polymorphism), variables, and `let x=... in ...` variable bindings, but no lambdas.  It illustrates a common approach for designing a typed interpreter but is missing enough that it won't spoil your fun.

Note: I have intentionally avoided using any intermediate or advanced Haskell features (e.g., the types `ExprU` and `ExprT` aren't unified in a single polymorphic type -- no "[trees that grow](http://www.jucs.org/jucs_23_1/trees_that_grow/jucs_23_01_0042_0062_najd.pdf)" for us!; I haven't used GADTs to [leverage the Haskell type system](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/glambda) in typing the target language; etc.).  These advanced techniques can lead to safer code -- and are also totally awesome so you definitely want to take a look at them in the future -- but they aren't necessary to get a basic typed interpreter working.

When writing interpreters, it's a good idea to turn on `-Wall` -- it'll remind you of which patterns (i.e., expression types) you've forgotten to handle:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
```

Also, to maintain our sanity, we'll need to use some monads:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Except
```

You mentioned in your question that you were struggling with two approaches:  dividing up operators by type at the outset versus somehow reflecting the operator types within the Haskell type system.  Your intuition about the first approach is spot on -- it's not going to work very well.  The second approach is do-able, but you're going to quickly run up against some very advanced Haskell techniques that you probably aren't ready for yet.

Instead, for our statically typed language, let's start by defining an entirely *untyped* abstract expression syntax.  Note that this is the sort of abstract syntax that might be generated by a parser that's completely ignorant of types:

```
-- Untyped expressions
data ExprU
  = FalseU | TrueU           -- boolean literals
  | NumU Double              -- numeric literal
  | VarU String              -- variable
  | UnU UnOp ExprU           -- unary operator
  | BinU BinOp ExprU ExprU   -- binary operator
  | LetU String ExprU ExprU  -- let x = expr1 in expr2
data UnOp = NegOp | NotOp
  deriving (Show)
data BinOp = PlusOp | MulOp | AndOp | OrOp | EqualsOp
  deriving (Show)
```

Note that we could write an interpreter for this directly.  However, the interpreter would have to deal with ill-typed expressions like:

```
BinU PlusOp FalseU (NumU 1)   -- False + 1
```

which would kind of defeat the whole purpose of defining a statically typed language.

The key insight is that we can take this untyped language and, before interpreting it, actually **type check** it!  There are cool techniques for using the Haskell type system to type check a target language, but it's much easier to just define a separate data type to represent expression types:

```
-- Simple expression types
data Typ
  = BoolT
  | NumT
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

For our operators, it'll be convenient to give them "types" as well:

```
-- Types of operators
data BinTyp = BinTyp Typ Typ Typ   -- binary ops: two arg types plus result type
data UnTyp  = UnTyp Typ Typ        -- unary ops: arg type plus result type
```

In a language with first-class functions, we'd probably combine these types into a single Haskell `Typ` that could represent not only "primitive" types like bools and nums but also function types, like `Bool -> Bool -> Bool`, and so on.  However, for this simple language, we'll keep "expression types" and "operator types" separate.

What do we do with these types?  Well, we take our untyped expressions `ExprU` and type check them by adding type annotations to each expression:

```
-- Typed expressions
data ExprT
  = BoolLit Bool
  | NumLit Double
  | VarT Typ String
  | UnT Typ UnOp ExprT
  | BinT Typ BinOp ExprT ExprT
  | LetT Typ String ExprT ExprT
```

Here, every constructor (except literals) has a `Typ` field that gives the type of the associated expression. (Actually, we could have added a `Typ` field to the literals, too, even though it's redundant.)  It'll be helpful to have a helper function to extract the type from an `ExprT`:

```
exprTyp :: ExprT -> Typ
exprTyp (BoolLit _) = BoolT
exprTyp (NumLit _) = NumT
exprTyp (VarT t _) = t
exprTyp (UnT t _ _) = t
exprTyp (BinT t _ _ _) = t
exprTyp (LetT t _ _ _) = t
```

Type checking will take place in a monad that keeps track of the types of variables (the one thing that we can't immediately figure out by inspecting expressions):

```
type TypContext = [(String, Typ)]   -- context of variable types
type TC = ExceptT Error (Reader TypContext)
```

For now, we can just use strings for our type errors:

```
type Error = String
```

Our type checker is surprisingly easy to write.  I takes an untyped expression `ExprU`, and adds the appropriate type annotations to make an `ExprT`:

```
tc :: ExprU -> TC ExprT
```

Creating the "typed version" of literals is easy:

```
tc (FalseU) = pure $ BoolLit False
tc (TrueU) = pure $ BoolLit True
tc (NumU x) = pure $ NumLit x
```

In our language, types for variables are easy too.  We only permit variables to be used *after* they've been defined (by a `LetU` binding -- see below), so their types will always be available in the current context:

```
tc (VarU var) = do
  mt <- asks (lookup var)
  case mt of
    Just t -> pure $ VarT t var
    Nothing -> throwError $ "undefined variable " ++ var
```

Types for unary operators are easy.  The only two unary operators are "negate" and "not", and both only apply to precisely one argument type and produce precisely one result type.  The `unTyp` function in the `where` clause tells us what `UnTyp` our unary operator has:

```
tc (UnU op e) = do
  let UnTyp targ tresult = unTyp op
  e' <- tc e
  let t = exprTyp e'
  when (t /= targ) $ throwError $ "op " ++ show op ++ 
    " expected arg of type " ++ show targ ++ ", got " ++ show t
  pure $ UnT tresult op e'
  where
    unTyp NegOp = UnTyp NumT NumT
    unTyp NotOp = UnTyp BoolT BoolT
```

For binary operators, `EqualsOp` is a little complicated.  We want to implement some ad hoc polymorphism so it can be applied to both booleans and numerics, though we'll require that that the types match (so `False == 1` isn't allowed).  So, we'll check the types of the arguments and ensure they match.  However, no matter what types the argument are, the type of the `BinU EqualsOp _ _` expression will always be boolean, so the typed version will always be `BinT BootT EqualsOp _ _`:

```
tc (BinU EqualsOp e1 e2) = do
  e1' <- tc e1
  e2' <- tc e2
  let t1 = exprTyp e1'
      t2 = exprTyp e2'
  when (t1 /= t2) $ throwError $ "op EqualOp needs to compare equal types"
  pure $ BinT BoolT EqualsOp e1' e2'
```

The other binary operators are monotyped, so we handle them the same as the (monotyped) unary operators above:

```
tc (BinU op e1 e2) = do
  let BinTyp targ1 targ2 tresult = binTyp op
  e1' <- tc e1
  e2' <- tc e2
  let t1 = exprTyp e1'
      t2 = exprTyp e2'
  when (t1 /= targ1) $ throwError $ "op " ++ show op ++
    " expected left arg of type " ++ show targ1 ++ ", got " ++ show t1
  when (t2 /= targ2) $ throwError $ "op " ++ show op ++
    " expected right arg of type " ++ show targ2 ++ ", got " ++ show t2
  pure $ BinT tresult op e1' e2'
  where
    binTyp PlusOp = BinTyp NumT NumT NumT
    binTyp MulOp = BinTyp NumT NumT NumT
    binTyp AndOp = BinTyp BoolT BoolT BoolT
    binTyp OrOp = BinTyp BoolT BoolT BoolT
    binTyp EqualsOp = error "internal error"
```

You might expect type checking of `LetU` expressions to be complicated, but it's pretty straightforward.  For `let x=exp1 in exp2`, we just calculate the type of `exp1`, and then add that type for `x` to the type context when calculating the type of `exp2`:

```
tc (LetU var e1 e2) = do
  e1' <- tc e1
  let t1 = exprTyp e1'
  e2' <- local ((var,t1):) $ tc e2
  let t2 = exprTyp e2'
  pure $ LetT t2 var e1' e2'
```

That's all there is to the type checker.

Once the type checker has been run to create an `ExprT` with a sound type, we'll want to evaluate it.  We'll represent values of expressions as:

```
-- Values
data Value
  = BoolV Bool
  | NumV Double
  deriving (Show)
```

Evaluation will take place in a monad with a context that assigned values to variables:

```
type ValContext = [(String, Value)]   -- context of variable values
type E = Reader ValContext
```

Note that we don't need an `ExceptT` transformer here.  It turns out that a type-checked program can't generate run-time errors in our language.

The evaluator/interpreter:

```
eval :: ExprT -> E Value
```

evaluates literals in the obvious way:

```
eval (BoolLit b) = pure $ BoolV b
eval (NumLit x) = pure $ NumV x
```

Variable values are looked up in the current context:

```
eval (VarT _ var) = do
  mt <- asks (lookup var)
  case mt of
    Just v -> pure $ v
    Nothing -> internalerror
```

Note that the type-checker has already ensured that variables are only used when they've been defined, so a failed lookup "can't happen".  We use the function `internalerror` (defined below) to satisfy the compiler that all cases have been handled so that we avoid a warning, but `internalerror` won't be called unless there's a bug in our interpreter.

Unary operators are interpreted like so:

```
eval (UnT _ op e) = run op <$> eval e
  where run NegOp (NumV x) = NumV (-x)
        run NotOp (BoolV b) = BoolV (not b)
        run _ _ = internalerror
```

Again, because of the type-checker, we can't be applying `NegOp` to a boolean or `NotOp` to a number, so the missing cases here (e.g., `run NegOp (BoolV b)`) can't happen.  Unfortunately, this means that we lose some of the benefits of having `-Wall` turned on -- if we forget to handle an new operator, it'll throw an `internalerror` at runtime.  <insert sad emoji>

Binary operators are interpreted similarly:

```
eval (BinT _ op e1 e2) = run op <$> eval e1 <*> eval e2
  where run EqualsOp (BoolV v1) (BoolV v2) = BoolV $ v1 == v2
        run EqualsOp (NumV v1) (NumV v2) = BoolV $ v1 == v2
        run PlusOp (NumV v1) (NumV v2) = NumV $ v1 + v2
        run MulOp (NumV v1) (NumV v2) = NumV $ v1 * v2
        run AndOp (BoolV v1) (BoolV v2) = BoolV $ v1 && v2
        run OrOp (BoolV v1) (BoolV v2) = BoolV $ v1 || v2
        run _ _ _ = internalerror
```

Because the Haskell `==` operator is polymorphic, we could have added an `Eq` instance to the `Value` type and replaced the first two cases with:

```
  where run EqualsOp v1 v2 = BoolV $ v1 == v2
```

but I wanted to illustrate the fact that `EqualsOp (BoolV v1) (NumV v2)` is never going to happen in a type-checked program.

Finally, we handle `LetT` like so:

```
eval (LetT _ var e1 e2) = do
  v1 <- eval e1
  local ((var,v1):) $ eval e2
```

That's our evaluator/interpreter.

Something interesting to note.  In our definition of `eval`, we never actually reference the type annotations that `tc` has added!  For this reason, we actually could have written `eval` to interpret the original untyped `ExprU` because the fact that `tc` completed would be enough to ensure that the `ExprU` could be interpreted without runtime type errors.  That is, in this simple language, the **fact** that a program type checks is way more important than the types that are calculated during type checking.  In more complicated languages, the type annotations might be more useful.

Anyway, that's it.  Here's full code plus an example program `expr1` in the target language:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Except

-- Untyped expressions
data ExprU
  = FalseU | TrueU           -- boolean literals
  | NumU Double              -- numeric literal
  | VarU String              -- variable
  | UnU UnOp ExprU           -- unary operator
  | BinU BinOp ExprU ExprU   -- binary operator
  | LetU String ExprU ExprU  -- let x = expr1 in expr2
data UnOp = NegOp | NotOp
  deriving (Show)
data BinOp = PlusOp | MulOp | AndOp | OrOp | EqualsOp
  deriving (Show)

-- Simple expression types
data Typ
  = BoolT
  | NumT
  deriving (Show, Eq)

-- Types of operators
data BinTyp = BinTyp Typ Typ Typ
data UnTyp  = UnTyp Typ Typ

-- Typed expressions
data ExprT
  = BoolLit Bool
  | NumLit Double
  | VarT Typ String
  | UnT Typ UnOp ExprT
  | BinT Typ BinOp ExprT ExprT
  | LetT Typ String ExprT ExprT

exprTyp :: ExprT -> Typ
exprTyp (BoolLit _) = BoolT
exprTyp (NumLit _) = NumT
exprTyp (VarT t _) = t
exprTyp (UnT t _ _) = t
exprTyp (BinT t _ _ _) = t
exprTyp (LetT t _ _ _) = t

-- Type check an expression
type Error = String
type TypContext = [(String, Typ)]   -- context of variable types
type TC = ExceptT Error (Reader TypContext)
runTC :: TC a -> a
runTC act = case runReader (runExceptT act) [] of
  Left err -> error err
  Right a -> a

tc :: ExprU -> TC ExprT
tc (FalseU) = pure $ BoolLit False
tc (TrueU) = pure $ BoolLit True
tc (NumU x) = pure $ NumLit x
tc (VarU var) = do
  mt <- asks (lookup var)
  case mt of
    Just t -> pure $ VarT t var
    Nothing -> throwError $ "undefined variable " ++ var
tc (UnU op e) = do
  let UnTyp targ tresult = unTyp op
  e' <- tc e
  let t = exprTyp e'
  when (t /= targ) $ throwError $ "op " ++ show op ++
    " expected arg of type " ++ show targ ++ ", got " ++ show t
  pure $ UnT tresult op e'
  where
    unTyp NegOp = UnTyp NumT NumT
    unTyp NotOp = UnTyp BoolT BoolT
tc (BinU EqualsOp e1 e2) = do
  e1' <- tc e1
  e2' <- tc e2
  let t1 = exprTyp e1'
      t2 = exprTyp e2'
  when (t1 /= t2) $ throwError $ "op EqualOp needs to compare equal types"
  pure $ BinT BoolT EqualsOp e1' e2'
tc (BinU op e1 e2) = do
  let BinTyp targ1 targ2 tresult = binTyp op
  e1' <- tc e1
  e2' <- tc e2
  let t1 = exprTyp e1'
      t2 = exprTyp e2'
  when (t1 /= targ1) $ throwError $ "op " ++ show op ++
    " expected left arg of type " ++ show targ1 ++ ", got " ++ show t1
  when (t2 /= targ2) $ throwError $ "op " ++ show op ++
    " expected right arg of type " ++ show targ2 ++ ", got " ++ show t2
  pure $ BinT tresult op e1' e2'
  where
    binTyp PlusOp = BinTyp NumT NumT NumT
    binTyp MulOp = BinTyp NumT NumT NumT
    binTyp AndOp = BinTyp BoolT BoolT BoolT
    binTyp OrOp = BinTyp BoolT BoolT BoolT
    binTyp EqualsOp = error "internal error"
tc (LetU var e1 e2) = do
  e1' <- tc e1
  let t1 = exprTyp e1'
  e2' <- local ((var,t1):) $ tc e2
  let t2 = exprTyp e2'
  pure $ LetT t2 var e1' e2'

-- Evaluate a typed expression
internalerror :: a
internalerror = error "can't happen, internal error in type checker"

-- Values
data Value
  = BoolV Bool
  | NumV Double
  deriving (Show)

type ValContext = [(String, Value)]   -- context of variable values
type E = Reader ValContext
runE :: E a -> a
runE act = runReader act []

eval :: ExprT -> E Value
eval (BoolLit b) = pure $ BoolV b
eval (NumLit x) = pure $ NumV x
eval (VarT _ var) = do
  mt <- asks (lookup var)
  case mt of
    Just v -> pure $ v
    Nothing -> internalerror
eval (UnT _ op e) = run op <$> eval e
  where run NegOp (NumV x) = NumV (-x)
        run NotOp (BoolV b) = BoolV (not b)
        run _ _ = internalerror
eval (BinT _ op e1 e2) = run op <$> eval e1 <*> eval e2
  where run EqualsOp (BoolV v1) (BoolV v2) = BoolV $ v1 == v2
        run EqualsOp (NumV v1) (NumV v2) = BoolV $ v1 == v2
        run PlusOp (NumV v1) (NumV v2) = NumV $ v1 + v2
        run MulOp (NumV v1) (NumV v2) = NumV $ v1 * v2
        run AndOp (BoolV v1) (BoolV v2) = BoolV $ v1 && v2
        run OrOp (BoolV v1) (BoolV v2) = BoolV $ v1 || v2
        run _ _ _ = internalerror
eval (LetT _ var e1 e2) = do
  v1 <- eval e1
  local ((var,v1):) $ eval e2

expr1 :: ExprU
expr1 = LetU "x" (BinU PlusOp (NumU 2) (NumU 3)) (LetU "y" (BinU MulOp (VarU "x") (NumU 5)) (BinU EqualsOp (VarU "y") (NumU 25)))

val1 :: Value
val1 = let e1' = runTC (tc expr1) in runE (eval e1')

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ val1
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but wow, that's way more of an in-depth response that I expected, and it's also thoroughly documented. This certainly helps. Thank you.